# C++ application: opening file fails because of language?

Tags: c++, file

I've written an application and it works fine. At least in the country I'm living in, Germany. As it seems a user from the UK cannot open/ find files with my application. Is that possible? Would I need to compile my program with a different codepage or something? These are my settings (Configuration properties, General):

[image: settings]

the user says that he receives an error message when he tries to open a file with my application: "windows cannot find c/documents"

This is the code I use for opening files:

```
ZeroMemory( &ofn , sizeof( ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof ( ofn );
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL ;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile ;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof( szFile );
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex =1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL ;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0 ;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir=NULL ;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST ;
GetOpenFileName( &ofn );
```

then I use:

```
str=ofn.lpstrFile;
    size_t found;
  found=str.find_last_of("\\");
  samp=str.substr(0,found+1);
```

and:

```
sprintf_s(filename,"%simg%u.jpg",samp.c_str(),xx);
            cvSaveImage(filename,framei);
```

Comment: What line in your code is the error coming from?

Comment: there's no error coming from any of those lines when I use the application. I have no idea why he is unable to open a file this way. Therefore I thought it might be a character issue (maybe slash or backslash) because I remember that sometimes in dosshell I had to type those characters with different keys (english keyboard layout) than I would usually type them in the editor.

Comment: You said he's getting "windows cannot find c/documents".  If that's an error that came from your application, you should be able to trace its origin, and ideally get a complete stack trace. It's not possible to debug without that information.

Comment: no, that error message did not originate from my application (I haven't implemented that type of error messages). Seems to originate from his Windows Explorer and I cannot reproduce it. That's why I was thinking of a language issue.

Comment: in the meantime I was able to reproduce a similar response of my application by canceling the open file dialog or by opening a file that cannot be handled. It wouldn't show his error message though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're assuming there's a folder called `C/documents`, which there probably is on your machine, and not on his.  Exactly what the error message says and has nothing to do with language or Sprache.

Comment: ZeroMemory( &ofn , sizeof( ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof ( ofn );
ofn.hwndOwner = NULL ;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile ;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof( szFile );
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.*\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex =1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL ;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0 ;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir=NULL ;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST ;
GetOpenFileName( &ofn );

str=ofn.lpstrFile;                                                  that is the code I use for opening the file. The str is a string which is later used this way: str.c_str() for opening it.

Comment: unfortunately he hasn't mailed me more than that. No, I don't refer to the documents folder. I suppose it's the folder where his file is located. I was thinking about a slash or backslash issue perhaps?

Comment: Um, I can't read that.  Please add that to your original post as an edit and format properly.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the user is typing "c/documents" in his File Open dialog, while he really wants to type "C:\Documents" or some such?

A screenshot of File Open dialog before he presses "Open" would be helpful.

Comment: if I can get a screenshot from him I'll post it. I guess he's very busy at the moment though. The thing is that the open file dialog itself is accepted but as soon as my application wants to access the file that message appears. In between a couple of windows (OpenCV) are created. And there should also appear a VFW dialog box asking for compression (which also doesn't seem to happen for him). What I really need to know is could there be such a language issue at work here - considering my settings above or the way I deal with the filename (as shown above)?

Comment: Since you specify OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST|OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, the FO dialog will not close until the user picks an existing path. c/documents is not a real path or file, so FO dialog simply shows a message and stays open.

Comment: yes, I suppose he just mistyped it. Probably he means c:\documents. Well, users often don't want to get too much into details, they just want things to work. But details are needed to solve such problems... will see if I can get more info from him. I have already asked him to answer some specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that the error message appears after a couple of windows, like OpenCV have opened. What possibly happens is some external application is executed, which tries to open a file in the directory selected in the File Open Dialog. If you don't properly quote the filename, it will fail when the filename incudes a space. "C:\Documents" is the first path of "C:\Documents and settings\Username\My Documents\File.ext". So if that user is using that directory, and you are using "C:\Dokumente\Datei.txt", you don't get the error, because there is no space in your filename. But this is only guessing, you did not post enough code to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I don't know. The user hasn't replied anymore. Either he has fixed the issue or given up. I guess he fixed it because I mailed him a checklist and certainly there was something in it that could help. As I stated in a previous comment I was able to reproduce some of the behavior he described when I opened a file that my application cannot read (it reads video files and I chose a txt file). Anyways, thx for trying to help!

Comment: You can try if you can reproduce the error if you open a file which is stored in a directory containing a space. If that works fine on your pc, this is not the problem.

Comment: I have created a directory called 1 b (with a space between the 1 and the b) and it works, yes. So whatever it is that causes an error it will stay a mystery unless he mails back :)